aws cdk failing to synth multiple Error Could not resolve package
I've pull a project that was working fine, however after doing the npm install; and then cdk synth; I'm getting a lot of could not resolve errors:
esbuild cannot run locally. Switching to Docker bundling.
✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "@aws-sdk/core"

    var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-sts/dist-cjs/index.js:256:26:
      256 │ var import_core = require("@aws-sdk/core");
          ╵                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  The module "./dist-es/index.js" was not found on the file system:

    var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/core/package.json:22:16:
      22 │       "module": "./dist-es/index.js",
         ╵                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "@aws-sdk/core" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error and leave the unresolved path in the bundle. You can also surround this "require" call with a try/catch block to handle this failure at run-time instead of bundle-time.

✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "@smithy/core"

    var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity/dist-cjs/index.js:76:26:
      76 │ var import_core = require("@smithy/core");
         ╵                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  The module "./dist-es/index.js" was not found on the file system:

    var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/node_modules/@smithy/core/package.json:20:16:
      20 │       "module": "./dist-es/index.js",
         ╵                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "@smithy/core" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error and leave the unresolved path in the bundle. You can also surround this "require" call with 
a try/catch block to handle this failure at run-time instead of bundle-time.

I'm relatively new with cdk, so I'm not pretty sure what happened since there was not any code changes, I'm guessing that the dependencies that docker is trying to pull are missing...
I've tried many solutions from these links, with no luck:

Why is aws cdk failing to synth and throwing "[ERROR] Could not resolve [package]"?
AWS CDK bundling lambda docker used instead of esbuild / debian WSL2
Resolving MODULE_NOT_FOUND Error for Internal Modules with TypeScript Path Aliases in AWS CDK during synthesis/deploymentt


I fixed this issue by installing esbuild to the project

I had the same issue today with next versions:
"@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider": "^3.321.1",
"@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.226.0",
"@aws-sdk/client-sqs": "^3.226.0",
"@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner": "^3.226.0",
"aws-cdk-lib": "^2.118.0",

I just uplifted them to:
"aws-cdk-lib": "^2.158.0",
"@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider": "^3.651.1"
...

And issue gone
I hope this helps you as well

I've tried this, however it did not work for me
